# Filter knowledge:articleList by channels

Tags: visualforce, soql, visualforce-component

I want to show Articles using **knowlede:articleList** filtered by channel.
In controller I have variables isCustomer, isPublic, isInternal, isPartner.
Maybe there is solution to bind **SOQL** and **knowlede:articleList**?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this using that component. I wanted to do something similar and ultimately custom wrote the entire thing.

Comment: I agree with you. But I need reuse existing code with less changes. I think I better create new visualforce component with these 4 attributes and controller for this component where I`ll be searching and filtering.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't even output those fields using that component. If you wanted to get really hacky, you could write it in javascript and make a map that inputs article number and outputs channel, then write some custom selects to show and hide from the already generated list.